# wp_handle_upload specified file failed upload test

Tags: uploads

The code I am using is practically the same as the codex. The $u and $m return true. Just the $error gives "specified file failed upload test".
Thanks for any help you can give.

FORM:

PHP

```
    if ($uploadedfile = $_FILES['amfile']) {$u = "Uploaded file set";} else  {$u = "Uploaded file NOT set";} 

    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    if ($movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides )) {$m = "Movefile file set";} else  {$m = "Movefile file NOT set";}  ;

    if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
        $error = "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        var_dump( $movefile );
    } else {

        $error = $movefile['error'];
    }

    echo $u . "<br>";
    echo $m . "<br>";
    echo $error . "<br>";
```

Comment: Which file you have to upload?

Comment: It's a pdf, doc or docx file. Loaded in a form and given like this: FORM:
<input type="file" name="amfile" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="amfile" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" aria-invalid="false">

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in your theme functions.php file :

```
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'file_and_ext_allow_for_user', 10, 4 );
function file_and_ext_allow_for_user( $types, $file, $filename, $mimes )
{
    if( false !== strpos( $filename, '.doc' ) ) {
        $types['ext'] = 'doc';
        $types['type'] = 'application/msword';
    } else if( false !== strpos( $filename, '.pdf' ) ) {
        $types['ext'] = 'pdf';
        $types['type'] = 'application/pdf';
    } else if( false !== strpos( $filename, '.docx' ) ) {
        $types['ext'] = 'docx';
        $types['type'] = 'application/docx';
    }
    return $types;
}
```

`File Upload Code`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['amfile'];

if( $uploadedfile ){

    $u = "Uploaded file set";

    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides ); 

    if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {

        $m = "Movefile file set";

        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        var_dump( $movefile);

    } else {
        $m = "Movefile file NOT set";
        /**
         * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
         * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
         */
        print_r($movefile);
        $error = $movefile['error'];
    }


} else  {
    $u = "Uploaded file NOT set";
} 

echo $u . "<br>";
echo $m . "<br>";
echo $error . "<br>";
```

Comment: I added the above Milan. I am assuming I have to amend my code somehow to access the $types[].

Comment: No need to change in your code just put above code in functions.php file.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help again. Yes, I did that and I still get the same outcome.

Comment: @lan please try above file upload code.

Comment: Many thanks for your input Milan. However the results are much the same.
$u = Uploaded file set
$m = Movefile file NOT set
$error = Specified file failed upload test.

Could it be to do with priorities set. I have this running from:
 add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'action_wpcf7_mail_sent', 20, 1 );